# Unable to locate essential development tools

Tags: installation

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 (VMware). I aim to implement OpenMP. Im using gcc 4.5 compiler. I tried to install it by using the command `sudo apt-get install gcc 4.5.`
Afterwards I proceed with `gcc -fopenmp foo.c`  BUT the output was:
`gcc: foo.c: No such file or directory gcc: no input files –.`
Now I tried to install the package by using :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install essential 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package essential.
```

I also tried  apt-cache search essential 
and after that  `sudo apt-get install essential-dev`
But the same error again,

```
 E: Unable to locate package essential-dev
```

Any solution,please?

Do I need to download any package? What should I do?

Comment: The fact that Im running Ubuntu in a virtual machine makes it more complicated?

Comment: No, absolutely not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install build-essential` installs the essential development tools.

As for the GCC error, you **need a source file `foo.c`** before you can attempt to compile it!

Comment: Which is the 1st thing to do?

Comment: First install, then create foo.c.

Comment: the output is:                                       ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 278 not upgraded.               How can I create  foo.c?

Comment: By sudo apt-get install gcc 4.5?

Comment: @Anita7 Try some C development pages. The Ask Ubuntu site is not a Q/A site for C or any other languages. Sorry.